# Small jQuery plugin for flair

Tags: app, javascript, jquery

[image: A screen cast of output]

See it in action at http://iamaust.in

### About

I know I know another flair plugin. I made this because I always wanted to write a jQuery plugin and for my new website I needed a Stack Overflow flair that actually fit my style. Everything in this plugin is designed to be style-able and customizable, rather than those silly images.

This is a customizable jQuery plugin for displaying your Stack Overflow information. I will expand on it as anyone suggests.

#### License

Anyone is free to modify, fork, pull, and create their own. I just would like a little credit to the original source.

#### Download

https://github.com/austinbv/StackOverflow-jQuery-Plugin

### Contact

Me on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)

### Extra

This is my first jQuery plugin and first Stack Apps application. Anyone who wants extra features or has suggestions feel free to fork and submit pull requests or just add suggestions in the comments. Please just make sure the [Sass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) and [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript) work. I compile the JavaScript code and CSS from them.